How to Unit test errorCaptured Lifecycle Hook in Vue3?
I am trying to trigger error from child component so that errorCapttured hook will be triggered in main.vue
Main.vue
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <q2-section class="section">
      <header>
         <h1>Testing</h1>
      </header>
      <router-view />
    </q2-section>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
   errorCaptured(err) {
      this.errorMethod(err);
   }
method: {
   errorMethod(err){
      console.error(err);
      return false;
   }
}
</script>

Unit Test Code


test('tests errorCaptured hook', async () => {
    wrapper = mount(Main, { global })

    let error = new Error('Generic Error');
    wrapper.vm.$options.errorCaptured.call(error);
    let spyOnError = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'errorMethod');
    expect(spyOnError).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
  })



Can someone help with unit testing code?

Spy on errorCaptured or console.error and throw an error in mocked q2-section? This depends on your testing setup

@EstusFlask do you have a working code, that I can refer?

No, it's written per case, and you didn't specify testing framework in the question. If you're familiar with mocking, consider updating the question with your current attempt that doesn't work, it's easier to fix something than write it from scratch without knowing the context

Does it use options api? This wasn't obvious from the original question. I'd expect the test to pass with wrapper.vm.$options.errorCaptured.call(wrapper.vm, error), not .call(error)

You need to set the spyOn before calling errorCaptured?
